# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ZKLib'

Tags: python, biometrics

I'm trying to connect to biometric device. I have installed 'Zklib' using (Pip). My code as follows

```
`import sys
 import zklib
 import time
 from zklib import zkconst
 zk = zklib.ZKLib("192.168.0.188", 4370)
 ret = zk.connect()
 print "connection:", ret`
```

When I execute this, I get an error

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ZKLib'
```

Help me to run this code successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following instead:

```
import sys
import time
from zklib import zklib, zkconst

zk = zklib.ZKLib("192.168.0.188", 4370)
ret = zk.connect()
print "connection:", ret
```

The `ZKlib` class is in `zklib.zklib` not `zklib`. It appears that there is a typo in the [Getting Started](https://github.com/AlSayedGamal/python_zklib#getting-started) section of their GitHub page (or they expect you to be in the `zklib` directory when running your code?).

Comment: Thank You very much Elethan. Your suggestion worked for me.